# JAVA Greatest common divisor recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I can't get this to run.There is a tester program and a method below. it says error identifier expected.Thanks in advance

```
public class 121tester{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in)
      System.out.println("Enter first number");
      int num1=input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter second number");
      int num2=input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The Greatest common factor of "+num1+" "+num2+" is "+GCD(num1,num2));

   } 
}


private static int GCD(int num1, int num2){
   if(num2==0){
   return num1;
   }
   return(GCD(num2, num1%num2);

}
```

Comment: Your example lacks `;` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Class name can't start with number. Change from

```
class 121tester
```

to

```
class Tester121
```

Another thing your GCD method should declare into inside class. It is better to use some IDE at initial stage of programming to remove compiler error.

Comment: where should I declare the method?

Comment: I don't know what that is :'(

Comment: it says I can't find the symbol GCD

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GCDTester{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter first number");
       int num1 = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter second number");
       int num2 = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("The greatest common factor of " + num1 + " " + num2 + " is " + gcd(num1,num2));
  }

  private static int gcd(int num1, int num2){
     if (num2 == 0) {
         return num1;
     }
     return gcd(num2, num1 % num2);
 }
```

}

But `@Masud` is correct, you should place the gcd method in a class of its own so that it can be used as an object in its own right.

Comment: I put it in it own class but I dont know how to properly call the method.

Comment: it says I can't find the symbol GCD

Comment: Then place all of the code above in a class of its own called GCDTester and store it in a file of the name.